# Electron.js emulate shortcut

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm defenitely is able to listen to shortcuts has been pressed like so:

```
electron.globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+Shift+L', () => {
  console.log('CommandOrControl+Shift+L is pressed');
});
```

But, what if I need vice versa? How can I emit such event? Emulate shortcuts pressing programmatically?

Or maybe I can do it with node.js somehow? Need just trigger shortcuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did that but you can try [sendInputEvent](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendinputeventevent).

As long as I can see; it is able to manage mouse, keys and keys modifiers like Ctrl+; Should be enough for most of use cases.